# Only getting 33mA from a USB port

Tags: usb, current, current-measurement

I attached split the end of a USB  wire and attached a switch. When I press the switch, I measure 5V from the port, but am only measuring 33mA. Why am I getting only 33mA instead of 100mA?

Comment: What is the other end of the USB cable plugged into?

Comment: It's connected to the multimeter.

Answer (score 4):

There is a decent chance that the computer is detecting a short and limiting the current back.

As pingswept said,

> try a 50 ohm resistor

This will stop the computer from thinking there is broken hardware connected.

Comment: I think Kortuk is on the right track. Try putting a 5 V / 0.1 A = 50 ohm resistor in series with the switch.